# call method with multiple parameters in onClick() of a button

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am new to Android and I am trying to Build a gallery app with Edit Activity. I have attached the screenshot of edit screen of my app. There is an ImageView, a SeekBar and 4 ImageButtons. The ImageButtons implements 4 edit functionality-Brightness,saturation and etc.. I have all methods for effects. All I want to know is when I click the imageButton(may be brightness), and drag the seekbar, the brightness should increase and similarly, when i click Contrast ImageButton and drag the seekbar, Contrast of Image should Increase. How can I implement it. Could Someone Please help me with it.. I tried using setOnTouchListener() for ImageButtons but that dint work, as it accepts only view as parameter and not Bitmap. Please help me.Thanks in Advance

Below is my Edit Activity

```
public class EditActivity extends Activity
   {
         private Bitmap bitmap;
         private ImageView image;
         private ImageButton bb,sab,shb,cb;
         private BitmapDrawable drawable;
         private SeekBar seekBar;

         @Override
         public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState)
         {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.filters);


    // Get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image id
    final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    image.setImageResource(imageAdapter.ids[position]);


    bb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.brightButton);
    drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    bb.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    sab=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.saturationButton);
    drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    sab.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    cb=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.contrastButton);
    drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    cb.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    shb=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sharpButton);
    drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
    shb.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


    SeekBar seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
        int brightness;

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, final int progress, boolean arg2)
        {
            brightness = progress;


                    Bitmap bBitMap = brightClicked(bitmap,progress);
                    image.setImageBitmap(bBitMap);
                    Bitmap saBitMap = sharpClicked(bitmap,progress);
                    image.setImageBitmap(saBitMap);
                    Bitmap cBitMap = saturationClicked(bitmap,progress);
                    image.setImageBitmap(cBitMap);
                    Bitmap shBitMap = contrastClicked(bitmap,progress);
                    image.setImageBitmap(shBitMap);

        }
    });


}



public Bitmap brightClicked(Bitmap bbitmap,int value)
{

    Bitmap bmOut= Bitmap.createBitmap(bbitmap.getWidth(), bbitmap.getHeight(),bbitmap.getConfig());
    int A, R, G, B;
    int pixel;

    for(int i=0; i<bbitmap.getWidth(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<bbitmap.getHeight(); j++)
        {
            pixel = bbitmap.getPixel(i, j);
            A = Color.alpha(pixel);
            R = Color.red(pixel);
            G = Color.green(pixel);
            B = Color.blue(pixel);
            R += value;
            if (R > 255)
            {
                R = 255;
            } else if (R < 0)
            {
                R = 0;
            }
            G += value;
            if (G > 255)
            {
                G = 255;
            } else if (G < 0)
            {
                G = 0;
            }
            B += value;
            if (B > 255)
            {
                B = 255;
            } else if (B < 0)
            {
                B = 0;
            }
            bmOut.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
        }
    }
    return bmOut;
}// and other methods of effects like sharpness,contrast..
```

Below is [Screenshot of EditImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsdlH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would begin with defining state so that the SeekBar can quickly determine which attribute it should be modifying (contrast, brightness, sharpness, saturation).  Throw these into an enum class (Google recommends avoiding [enums in Android](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Overhead)) if you like or define them within the class itself as ints.  For example:

```
public class EditActivity extends Activity {
    private int currentState;
    private static final int SATURATE = 0;
    private static final int CONTRAST = 1;
    ....
}
```

Now you can just have the state be updated based on the button clicked:

```
bb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.brightButton);
bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          currentState = BRIGHTNESS;
      }
}
```

Then use a switch-case statement to quickly determine the state of the Activity and adjust the image accordingly through your image methods.

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, final int progress, boolean arg2)
    {
        brightness = progress;
        switch (currentState) {
               case (SATURATE) : 
                     image.setImageBitmap(saturationClicked(bitmap,progress));
                     break;
               case (CONTRAST) :
                     image.setImageBitmap(contrastClicked(bitmap,progress));
                     break;
```

It looks like your current implementation would run all your filters on the image any time the seek bar is moved, which I imagine would cause horrible performance.  A switch case would just help you avoid that.

Comment: Thank you so much.. This is working .. :).. You really Helped me a lot :)

Comment: np. you could also improve performance by removing several lines of redundant code: drawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();
    bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();  after the first call, you don't need to getDrawable() or getBitmap() as you already have it and could save you several cycles of processing.

Comment: Oh yes. I will reduce it. Thank you :)